# How to define map fusion in the Pure language?

Tags: functional-programming, pattern-matching

I'm experimenting with the [Pure](http://purelang.bitbucket.org/) language based on term rewriting.

I want to define ["map fusion"](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC_optimisations#Fusion) using an equation, like this:

```
> map f (map g list) = map (f . succ . g) list;
```

(The `succ` is there to verify that the rule kicks in.)

However, it doesn't seem to work:

```
> map id (map id [2,3,4]);
[2,3,4]
```

The [Pure manual](http://puredocs.bitbucket.org/pure.html) says that

> expressions are evaluated using the “leftmost-innermost” reduction strategy

So I suppose what's happening is that the innermost `map id [2,3,4]` expression is reduced first, so my rule never kicks in.

How to make map fusion work, then?

Here's a related experiment. The first rule doesn't kick in:

```
> a (b x) = "foo";
> b x = "bar";
> a (b 5);
a "bar"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have read [the manual](http://puredocs.bitbucket.org/pure.html#macros) more closely. What I needed to do is to turn the pattern into a macro using the `def` keyword. This way it works:

```
> def map f (map g list) = map (f . succ . g) list;
> map id (map id [2,3,4]);
[3,4,5]
```